# Proving a recursively defined sequence is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Prove that the sequence $x_1=1,x_2=2,x_n=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})$ is bounded $1 \leq x_n \leq 2$.

To prove this by induction would I have to use strong induction?Or is the general form of mathematical induction sufficient?

Is this proof sufficient?

Since the result holds for $x_1,x_2,$ and $x_3=\frac{3}{2}$ the base holds.

Assume for all integers $n \leq k$, the result holds.

Then $\frac{1}{2}(1+1)=1 \leq \frac{1}{2}(x_{k-1}+x_{k})=x_{k+1} \leq \frac{1}{2}(2+2)=2$

Answer (score 1):

The crucial thing you need here is that, if $a<b$, then $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$.

Hence $\min\{x_{k-1},x_{k-2}\}\le x_k\le \max\{x_{k-1},x_{k-2}\}$.